# Best way to set-up a linear mixed model analysis for medical device bench data?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear

I am working on a bench study comparing two commercial devices (Device X and Device Y) and their ability to hold contact force over 30 seconds on a substrate at 2 independent angles (16 and 130). This will be done on fresh devices and after multiple articulations (0, 50, 100, and 120). The more articulations = device fatigue, so predicting it can reduce contact force stability (i.e. more variability). The output we are looking at is 'mean contact force' (over 30 seconds) and any variability. Since these samples are not independent, I anticipate the need for a linear mixed model analysis. Any preference of using GraphPad or R. If R, how would I establish the initial lmm equation with the multiple levels?

Comment: What exactly are the levels you are interested in/ the correlations you expect. Also for mixed models in R see here: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification

Comment: What is the purpose of your study (what is the research question in terms of your data) ?

Comment: @LukasLohse The levels we are interested in studying is device, # of articulations, and angle. We want to see whether there is a difference in contact force (mean and variability) between device X and Y at the different angles and with increasing # of articulations.

Comment: Optimally you can write out what you expect the response variable to be distributed as, depending on your variables. Right now I don't see why articulations and angle wouldn't be best described as fixed effects and therefor you don't need a mixed model.

Comment: @LukasLohse I was under the assumption that the different articulations groups are not independent. for example, the same device that underwent 50 articulations will also undergo another 50, to reach 100. If a mixed model is not required, should I consider a three-way ANOVA?

Comment: So you have multiple devices of type X or Y? If so then the individual device would be the relevant level for the random effects/correlation structure

Comment: Yes, that's correct, we have 10 devices of X and Y. In addition to device, the angle (16 or 130) and # of articulations (0, 50, 100, and 120) would also be a fixed or random variable right? I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the lme4 equation in R.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to both check mean and variance I'd recommend `glmmTMB` with its `dispformula`. Familiarize yourself with what that actually does. You might start here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/615211/341520

There are also more advanced options with proper correlation structures. You don't have that many devices though,but check it out here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html

Anyway here's a simulation with huge effects an looking at everything that is not an interaction. You might start from here:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed("0815")
n_device <- 10
device_random_effect <- rnorm(n_device*2, sd = 1)
dat <- data.frame(articulations = rep(as_factor(c(0, 50, 100, 120)), n_device), 
           angle = as_factor(rep(rep(c(16, 130), each = 4), n_device)),
           device_id = rep(1:(2*n_device), each = 8),
           type = rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 8*n_device))

dat$y <-  5 - as.integer(dat$articulations) + 1*(dat$angle == "16") + 
  device_random_effect[dat$device_id] + 
  rnorm(8*2*n_device, sd = 1 + 2*(dat$angle == "16") + 3*(dat$type == "Y"))
# the plot does not show much exept the higher variance for y
ggplot(dat, aes( y = y, x = articulations, color = type)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(angle))
# straight forard model
my_model <- glmmTMB(y ~ articulations + angle + type+ (1|device_id), 
        dispformula = ~ articulations + angle + type,
        data = dat)

summary(my_model)
# advanced and not properly converging 
my_model2 <- glmmTMB(y ~ articulations + angle +type+ us(articulations + angle|device_id), 
                    dispformula = ~ type - 1,
                    data = dat)
summary(my_model2)
```